R Markdown 508 Compliance for word documents
What R packages or workarounds are available to add to a rmd file to include table alt-text, reading order, and keyboard accessibility order that produce word and PDF documents?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
